# Toggle Night Light mode in Android by code

Tags: android, android-night-mode

Is it possible to activate Night Light mode in Android?
I am developing an Automation app and depending on user conditions, I need to activate the Night mode.
It is call differently depending on the vendor (again, Android is not very standard) like Blue Filter, or Reading mode.
I haven't found anywhere in the net to code this.

I saw this [link](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/display/night-light) but I don't understand it. I need a function like this one:

```
public void setNightMode(Context target , boolean state){

    if (state) {
        //Enable Blue Light Filter
    } else {
        //Disable Blue Light Filter
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Source.android.com is not developer.android.com, and that code is addressed at device manufacturers looking to implement [`ColorDisplayManager`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/main/core/java/android/hardware/display/ColorDisplayManager.java)/[`ColorDisplayService`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/services/core/java/com/android/server/display/color/ColorDisplayService.java). Not third party apps.

With this said, I'm not really sure if there are non-root ways to directly control them, but at least the `night_display_activated` and `night_display_auto_mode` secure system settings can be [reportedly](https://xdaforums.com/t/guide-fix-yellowish-display-aka-night-light-rootless-and-magisk-o.4130793/) influenced with the right adb permissions (which a normal application could use through Shizuku I guess). Pie might be slightly more quirky ([possibly](https://community.oneplus.com/thread/976467) only working if the automatic schedule is enabled) but still in the realm of doable.

Also please make sure not to eventually loose the distinction between **Night*****Mode*** (which is just the "UI darkness" thing) and **Night*****Display*** (i.e. the warmer screen tint at hand).

Answer (score -2):

Yes, You can set the mode based on you app preference for example below code will set the night mode

```
val mode = AppPreference.getInt(AppPreference.PREF_KEY_THEME, Theme.MODE_DAY)
    when (mode) {
        Theme.MODE_DAY -> AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO)
        Theme.MODE_NIGHT -> AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES)
        Theme.MODE_AUTO -> AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_AUTO)
    }
```

You can follow the directory structure as in image.
[image]

From those color values you can supply different colors for background and font. Even you can have different styles for night mode.

Comment: Sorry, I am not talking about setting that mode just for my app. I am talking about activating that mode to the whole system. Just like System settings --> Display --> Blue Light filter but by code.

Comment: I understand from this line 'Device manufacturers can enable the default implementation of the feature by using the following flags defined in: /android/frameworks/base/core/res/res/values/config.xml" like this is for system apps.